# output csv file then display status message in a label is causing error

Tags: asp.net, webforms

This code generates a **csv** file. I've wrapped the code inside a try/catch block so that user will get feedback.

```
protected void btnExportPriceSheet_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            //...
            string csvText = vInfo.GenerateVendorPriceSheetCSVText(SuppID);
            byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(csvText);
            string exportFileName = string.Format("VendorPriceSheet_{0}.csv", 1);

            lblError.Text = "Price Sheet successfully generated.";
            lblError.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Blue;

            OutputFile(data, exportFileName);                
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            lblError.Text = 
                     string.Format("Export Price Sheet failed: {0}", ex.Message);
            lblError.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
        }
    }
```

When there is an error, the error is displaying correctly. However, when things go well, no message is displayed. I've tried to switch places so that displays the success message after `OutputFile(data, exportFileName);`, but I'm getting an exception: "**Unable to evaluate expression because the code is optimized or a native frame is on top of the call stack.**"

I suspect that the response is returned as file to download, so there is no html in that response.

Any way to solve that probleme?

Comment: What does `OutputFile` at all? I guess it's writing the bytes to the response(f.e. via `Response.BinaryWrite`) and call `Response.End` or something like that.

Comment: I think so, because it's no even displaying the success message. Do you think I should instead issue a ajax call, then check whether the call was a success? In fact, for now I'm posting back the page.